# Where can I find tutorials on quantum variational algorithms?

Tags: resource-request, vqe

I am interested in learning about quantum algorithms, especially quantum variational algorithms. I would like to know where I can find resources that delve into specific quantum variational algorithms and provide tutorials on how to run such algorithms using Qiskit, PennyLane, or any other free platform.

I have a basic theoretical knowledge of the quantum Fourier transform and Shor's algorithm, but I lack practical implementation knowledge.

---

***[Cross-posted on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/765555/58382)***

Comment: Review papers might help a lot such as [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.05176) and [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01382).

Answer (score 2):

It's the second time I advertise for this blog, so I guess I'll just say that I'm not affiliated with the blogger in any way! The best resource I could read on VQE was [Musty Thoughts' article on it](https://www.mustythoughts.com/variational-quantum-eigensolver-explained). In fact, it's the first part of an ongoing series on variational algorithms, where he explains not only how they work, but also their limitations and the challenges they have to overcome in the future. Definitely worth checking it out.

Some frameworks wrote tutorials on thse kind of algorithms. For instance, Qiskit has [a tutorial on how to apply VQE to chemistry problems](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-applications/simulating-molecules-using-vqe) and [a short tutorial on how to use the `Estimator` primitive to solve a variational problem](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/ibm-runtime/tutorials/vqe_with_estimator.html).

Xanadu on the other hand also wrote [a tutorial to run VQE with Pennylane](https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_vqe.html) and made [a YouTube video on it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Xnxa6tzPeA).

In fact, VQE's such an important algorithm that I think that most frameworks would have their own tutorial on how to implement it. For instance, you could also find [a tutorial for cirq here](https://quantumai.google/cirq/experiments/variational_algorithm). It's thus up to you to choose the framework you're the most proficient with!

From what I've seen, most of these tutorials only assume basic knowledge of Quantum Computing (not in chemistry), so you should be fine with at least one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The Qiskit textbook has added a section towards variational algorithms and goes over the code as well as a bit of the math involved which helped me better understand how to implement variational algorithms. You could also earn a badge after a short assessment if interested! [Here](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/algorithm-design/variational) is the link to the chapter, I recommend checking it out!

Answer (score 1):

I've been making a series of Jupyter notebooks introducing the VQE for beginners in [this Git repo](https://github.com/bentomontenegro/vqe_basics-qiskit_1.0). Keep an eye out for it, because I intend to update it with more advanced topics in the near future. Hope you will enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an example of VQE applied, Amazon Braket provides a [example Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/amazon-braket/amazon-braket-examples/blob/main/examples/hybrid_quantum_algorithms/VQE_Chemistry/VQE_chemistry_braket.ipynb) of using VQE for computing the potential energy surface of a Hydrogen molecule.

That repo can be used via [Amazon Braket notebook instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/braket/latest/developerguide/braket-get-started-create-notebook.html) or utilized locally.